# Convert timestamp to DateTime flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, mobile, timestamp

I have this value (int):

**230523110326**

Being:

- 23 - Day
- 05 - Month
- 23 - Year
- 11 - Hour
- 03 - Minutes
- 26 - Seconds

I want to turn it now into a DateTime, since i'm using this method

`DateTime.fromMillisecondsSiceEpoch(230523110326, isUtf: true)`

but he is returning me this

`DateTime (1977-04-22 02:11:50.366Z)`.

Would anyone have a solution?

I already tried multiplying the value by 1000, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input is already an integer, you can do integer arithmetic to extract the parts:

```dart
void main() {
  var timestamp = 230523110326;

  var components = <int>[];
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i += 1) {
    components.add(timestamp % 100);
    timestamp = timestamp ~/ 100;
  }

  var [seconds, minutes, hour, twoDigitYear, month, day] = components;
  var year = fromTwoDigitYear(twoDigitYear); // See below.

  var dateTime = DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds);
  print(dateTime); // Prints: 2023-05-23 11:03:26.000
}
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76273568/ for how to convert a two-digit year to a four-digit yaer.

Finally, I'd like to point out that it's unclear whether your timestamp format is supposed to be in a `ddMMyy` or in a `yyMMdd` format because your particular example ambiguously uses `23` for both the day and two-digit year.  The code above assumes `ddMMyy` to match the order you listed, but `yyMMdd` would be more sensible for an integer timestamp since it would allow comparing (most) timestamps with an integer comparison. (However, the use of two-digit years instead of four-digit years means that such comparisons wouldn't work properly for years before 2000.)

Answer (score 0):

My friend, `fromMillisecondsSiceEpoch` is not like what you're thinking. Read more about Epoch:

- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/millisecondsSinceEpoch.html
- https://api.dart.dev/be/169657/dart-core/DateTime/DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch.html

**Easy explain:**

In programming and time systems, the "epoch" generally refers to a fixed point in time that serves as a reference for calculating other time values. The epoch is often a specific date, a starting point, or a significant marker in the time calculation process.

In the case of `DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch` in Flutter, the epoch typically refers to the "Unix epoch" or "Unix timestamp." The Unix epoch is a widely used time system in programming. It is defined as 00:00:00 UTC on January 1, 1970. The `DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch` method expects you to provide a time value in milliseconds since the Unix epoch. It then returns a corresponding DateTime object for that moment in time.

**What should do in your case?**

Do by hand, use method `String. substring(first, last)` to get one by one date, month, year, hour, minute, second. Example:

```
String date = "230523110326". substring(0,2); // then convert to int as you like
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  var value = 230523110326;
  var svalue = value.toString();
  var list = <int>[];
  for (var i = 0; i < svalue.length/2; i++) {
    var ss = svalue.substring(2*i, 2*i+2);
    if (i==2) ss = '20$ss';
    list.add(int.parse(ss));
  }
  var dt = DateTime(list[2],list[1],list[0],list[3],list[4],list[5]);
  print(dt);
  print('\nJob done!');
}
```

Output:

```
2023-05-23 11:03:26.000

Job done!
```